# Shell script cronjob

Tags: linux, shell, cron, directadmin

I need a shell script that would run two .sh files which are in the directory: `/opt/tomcat-latest/bin`

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /opt/tomcat-latest/bin
./shutdown.sh
./startup.sh
```

Would this code achieve my goal? If so how do I make it on a cron job that runs every 2 hours? I have a Linux Centos VPS and DirectAdmin admin panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to run directly the commands with its full path from cron, instead of using a sh script.

Something like this in the crontab would work :

```
* */2 * * * /opt/tomcat-latest/bin/shutdown.sh && /opt/tomcat-latest/bin/startup.sh
```

That would run every 2 hours 
you can edit crontab with crontab -e and check the crontab syntax here : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab

Comment: `[root@server bin]# crontab -u root -l` 

Gave:

`* */2 * * * /opt/tomcat-latest/bin/shutdown.sh && /opt/tomcat-latest/bin/startup.sh`


So it should all be good now right?